openpyxl Scatter plot w/ flitted x/y axis
starting from the example at:
https://openpyxl.readthedocs.io/en/stable/charts/scatter.html#scatter-charts
original scatter plot](https://i.sstatic.net/82ypMpIT.png)
I would like to generate this plot  where x anx y axis are just exchanged (i.e. "percentage" on horizontal and "size" on vertical axis), w/o altering in the data in the excel sheet and w/ having the same labels for each series set w/ "title_from_data=True".
It sounds pretty easy, but I did nowhere find any hint how to do this.

In general very straight forward. Simply change all X-references to Y-references vice versa.
But title_from_data=True cannot be used while creating the series, because this only works for default scatter charts where multiple series have Y-values mapped to same X-values, thus series-titles come from references above Y-values. So for this special case, the series title must be created from title-references using SeriesLabel and StrRef.
Example:
from openpyxl import Workbook
from openpyxl.chart import (
    ScatterChart,
    Reference,
    Series,
)
from openpyxl.chart.series import SeriesLabel, StrRef

wb = Workbook()
ws = wb.active

rows = [
    ['Size', 'Batch 1', 'Batch 2'],
    [2, 40, 30],
    [3, 40, 25],
    [4, 50, 30],
    [5, 30, 25],
    [6, 25, 35],
    [7, 20, 40],
]

for row in rows:
    ws.append(row)

chart = ScatterChart()
chart.title = "Scatter Chart"
chart.style = 13
chart.x_axis.title = 'Percentage'
chart.y_axis.title = 'Size'

yvalues = Reference(ws, min_col=1, min_row=2, max_row=7)
for i in range(2, 4):
    xvalues = Reference(ws, min_col=i, min_row=2, max_row=7)
    series = Series(yvalues, xvalues)
    series_title_ref = Reference(ws, min_col=i, min_row=1, max_row=1)
    series.title = SeriesLabel(strRef=StrRef(series_title_ref))
    chart.series.append(series)

ws.add_chart(chart, "A10")

wb.save("scatter.xlsx")

